# Boost Unit test framework fixtures using free functions

Tags: boost, boost-unit-test-framework

How does one use free functions for fixtures (setup and teardown) as hinted here: [flexible models](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/models.html) ? The docs don't show an example and the library tests do not use this scenario. I am looking for an example for a test suite.

Comment: The page linked also "hints" [where](http://www.boost.org/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/decorator_fixture.html) you can find a complete example of a test module which uses those models.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that example (if we are talking about the same thing) but it uses the free functions to construct a fixture used in a test case, not suite. However, after reading through the source code, it seems that the same would work for a test suite. Not sure if it's kosher to add an answer to my question, though.

Comment: It's perfectly fine (and encouraged) to answer your own question if you have found a solution to the problem, especially if it can help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this works for me:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE foo

#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
namespace utf = boost::unit_test;

void setup ()    { BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("set up fun"); }
void teardown () { BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("tear down fun"); }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(bar, *utf::fixture (&setup, &teardown))

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test1) {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("running test1");
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test2) {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("running test2");
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Running:

```
$ clang++ -I/usr/local/include test.cpp && ./a.out --log_level=all
Running 2 test cases...
Entering test module "foo"
test.cpp:9: Entering test suite "bar"
set up fun
test.cpp:11: Entering test case "test1"
running test1
test.cpp:13: info: check true has passed
test.cpp:11: Leaving test case "test1"; testing time: 56us
test.cpp:16: Entering test case "test2"
running test2
test.cpp:18: info: check true has passed
test.cpp:16: Leaving test case "test2"; testing time: 36us
tear down fun
test.cpp:9: Leaving test suite "bar"; testing time: 148us
Leaving test module "foo"; testing time: 244us
...
```

Notice the call to setup before the suite is run and the call to teardown at the end.